# I have voted to reopen a question - here's why

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I have voted to re-open this question:

[How to save Gantt and PERT as a GIF image?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/how-to-save-gantt-and-pert-as-a-gif-file)

This is a question about how to use a very popular Project Management tool to undertake a very common Project Management task. If this question is off-topic then so are very many other questions along the lines of "How do I do [this thing] using MS-Project" and they should also all be closed.

I don't believe this is off-topic in spirit, even if it is when going "by the book", the OP is not asking for toolset recommendations but are, in effect, asking for how to solve a PM problem they are currently experiencing.

I am not sure how the re-open voting process works, but I suppose I am asking here "Should this question be reopened"?

Comment: +1, Thanks for voting to re-open and bringing this to Meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now see the MS Project tag and can see where you're coming from.  We generally try to keep all relevant content in the body and just use tags for categorization for grouping and searching.

If someone can give the question an edit to expand it out a bit more, I'd be happy to reopen it.  I'd suggest making it clear it's an MS Project problem, as well as just adding some additional details that would help future visitors find this information and understand it contains solutions to an MS Project problem.

If someone does this, just flag it for moderator attention, or drop a link in the [PMSE Notice Board](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board).

**UPDATE:** I went ahead and made some edits and reopened the post. Thanks for bringing this to meta!